# Who first proved that $[X,Y]$ is a group under these conditions?

Tags: algebraic-topology, reference-request, homotopy-theory

In his **Introduction to Homotopy Theory**, Arkowitz proves that:

1. If $X$ is simply connected and co-$H$, then $[X,Y]$ is a group,
2. If $Y$ is an $H$-space, then $[X,Y]$ is a group

where the multiplicative structure is induced by the respective multiplicative structures in $X$ and $Y$.

Arkowitz gives the full proof, and for 2. he cites

*James, I.M.: On H-spaces and their homotopy groups*.

He does not cite anyone for the first result.

I would like to confirm that he was indeed the first person to prove this result 1., and (for citation purposes) that the aforementioned book is the place where the result first appears in the literature?

Answer (score 2):

These results are not true without (co-)associativity assumptions. In general these sets will only be algebraic loops.

The correct statement for the first part is as follows.

> Let $X$ be a connected co-H-complex and $Y$ a space. Then $[X,Y]$ is an algebraic loop if either $(i)$ $X$ is simply connected, or $(ii)$ $Y$ is nilpotent.

I believe this statements was proved for the first time as Theorem 2.3 of the following paper.

> P. Hilton, G. Mislin, J. Roitberg, *On Co-H-Spaces*, Comment. Math. Helvetici **53** (1978) 1-14.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In using the term (co-) $H$-space, is it common to specify homotopy (co-) associativity in this way? I do see now that it probably is, and there only a few sources that assume associativity like that within the terminology $H$ or co-$H$.

Would the below alternative alteration also be correct (using that connected $H$-space is nilpotent)?

Let $X$ and $Y$ be connected. Then $[X,Y]$ is a group if either $X$ is a simply-connected, and a co-associative co-$H$ space, or $Y$ is an associative $H$-space.

Comment: Yes. Taking $X=Y$ the loop structure grants left and right homotopy inverses. When the structure is (co-)associative, the two inverses agree. There results a group structure in the general case. Many authors use the term *H-group* for an associative H-space with inverses. Similarly *H-cogroup*.